# Android setError to stop executing rest of code

Tags: android

In the onClick event of a button i want to chek if the edit texts are null. If one edit text is null i want to show a message and stop the executing the rest of code.
`

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String client = txtClient.getText().toString();
        if( txtClient.getText().toString().length() == 0 )              
            txtClient.setError( "First name is required!" ) ;              

        String adresa = txtAdresa.getText().toString(); 
        String localitate = txtLocalitate.getText().toString(); 
        String telefon = txtTelefon.getText().toString();
```

`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `return` keyword to exit out of the function early in your `if` block:

```
if( txtClient.getText().toString().length() == 0 ) {          
   txtClient.setError( "First name is required!" );   
   return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Carl for your answer, it is what i need.

Answer (score -2):

```
if( txtClient.getText().toString().length() == null ) {          
    txtClient.setError( "First name is required!" );   
    return;
}
```

Comment: How is this different than Carl's answer, besides that it is a worse answer because you only provide code and you check for null instead?

Comment: This code won't compile. The return value of `length()` is an int, which cannot be compared to `null` in Java (although it can in C++).

Comment: That was horrible. I saw that he mentioned 'checking his EditText for null' and saw that Carl provided an if statement to do that but checked for '0'... which I foolishly replaced with 'null'. Hope I didn't hold you up any. Sorry